# heap corruption detected after normal block c++

Tags: c++, массивы, память, динамические-массивы

пару дней назад начал изучать с++ и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Цель - написать программу по вводу чисел и подсчету их среднего значения. Организовал динамический массив под это дело и в него записываю пользовательский ввод, однако постоянно вылезает ошибка heap corruption detected after normal block. Не понимаю, где вообще расположен неверный участок.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int numbersInArray = 0;
    double *input = new double [numbersInArray];
    double test;
    while(numbersInArray < 10)
    {
        cin >> test;
        if (!cin)
            break;
        else
        {
            numbersInArray++;
            input[numbersInArray - 1] = test;
        }
    }
    double average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersInArray; i++)
    {
        average += input[i];
    }
    cout << "Average value: " << average/numbersInArray << endl;
    int numbersGreaterThenAverage = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersInArray; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] > average)
            numbersGreaterThenAverage++;
    }
    cout << "Numbers greater then average: " << numbersGreaterThenAverage << endl;
    delete[] input;
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, половину гугла перерыл, не нашел решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Динамический массив в языке C++ имеет два значения: массив переменного размера(т.е. способным к добавлению и удалению в нём элементов) и массив, который мы разместили в куче(`heap`). В данном случае вы используете второй вид динамического массива, который сам по себе не меняет своих размеров.

Когда мы хотим считать и записать элементы массива, то у нас стоит выбор какой использовать: статический или динамический(1 или 2). Если количество элементов фиксировано(т.е. мы изначально знаем), то под это отлично подойдёт обычный статический массив, а если же количество элементов вводится с клавиатуры, то мы используем динамический, т.к. по стандарту в языке C++ количество элементов в статическом массиве должно быть известно в момент компиляции, никак не исполнения.
В вашем случае, как я понял, количество элементов фиксировано и равно 10. Тогда и вовсе динамический массив никак не обязателен.

Распишу решение в 3-х видах: с использованием статического и динамического 1-го и 2-го вида.

Статический(неспособный к растягиванию массив, выделенный в `stack`):

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int ARR_SIZE = 10;
     arr[ARR_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; ++i)
        std::cin >> arr[i];

    //обрабатываем элементы массива
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Динамический(неспособный к растягиванию массив в `heap`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int numbersInArray;
    std::cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
    std::cin >> numbersInArray;
    double *arr = new double[numbersInArray];
    for(int i = 0; i < numbersInArray; ++i)
        cin >> arr[i];
    //обрабатываем элементы массива
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Динамический(cпособный к растягиванию массив, внутри сам выделен в `heap`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector < double > arr;
    int numbersInArray;
    std::cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
    std::cin >> numbersInArray;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbersInArray; ++i)
    {
        double temp_variable;
        cin >> temp_variable;
        arr.push_back(temp_variable);
    }
    //обрабатываем элементы массива
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот это очень полезный ответ, спасибо! Про статический я знал, но тут особенность программы в том, что 10 - условный максимум, после которого программа сама завершает возможность ввода. Но если ввести не число, а, к примеру, символ 'f', программа завершает ввод, и считает только те числа, которые были введены до этого, то есть их может быть 7. Как я понял, в статическом массиве не инициализированные элементы обращаются в 0 и повлияют на среднее значение. Данные задачи теперь буду решать через vector, как я понял через обычные массивы такого выполнить не получится. Спасибо за подробный ответ)

Answer (score 2):

```
int numbersInArray = 0;
double *input = new double [numbersInArray];
```

Итак, вы выделили память под... **нуль** элементов. Отсюда и все неприятности. Представьте, что вам выдали нуль-комнатную квартиру - и куда вы будете завозить мебель? :)

Если уж хотите работать не с готовым вектором, например - то выделяйте память с запасом, чтоб ее хватило. Будучи выделенной, сама по себе память не перераспределяется.

Comment: но я ведь далее увеличиваю размер массива перед записью в него значения, да и среднее значение все-таки выводится. Я думал, что размер можно увеличивать во время выполнения программы. Так не работает в с++?

Comment: Вы не увеличивали размер массива, а увеличивали значение никак не относящейся к нему переменной. Что касается увеличения размера массива во время выполнения программы, так это просто создание нового массива большего размера и перенесение туда значений предыдущего массива. В плюсах так, конечно, можно делать.

Comment: то есть увеличивать размер уже созданного массива нельзя в c++?

Comment: Нет, это делается не так. Вы должны выделить новый массив, скопировать туда старые элементы, старый массив освободить... Тот же `vector` это делает "за сценой", незаметно для вас, но если вы работаете с "голым" массивом - тут вся ответственность за него на вас возложена...

Comment: Проводя аналогию с квартирой - если вы в ордер впишете хоть 15 комнат - их от этого в уже построенной квартире не прибавится... Нужно строить новую и мебель туда из старой перевозить...